# How to assign date at each insertion in sql server c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am working in C#.

I have columns `emp_id, sick_leaves, vacation_leaves, admin_leaves, from_date, to_date` in a SQL Server table.

User can assign leaves to any employee using a form. Leaves are inserted in cells and respective date is picked from datetimepicker and stored in database.

When the same employee wants more leaves, leaves are added to his previous leaves.

But the problem is when the same employee wants more leaves after some days, how to store each of leaves date wise in database. e.g 2 sick_leaves from 02/02/2014 to 04/02/2014. Then 3 more sick_leaves from 10/02/2014 to 13/02/2014.

After that I want search leaves on monthly and annually basis, but I have to solve the above problem to do the later.

Hope you understand the question. Please give me some solutions asap.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My be i didn't understand what you are asking... you are wanting to have a single record for each employee and just update the leave days... may be this is what you are looking for..
but instead of this you can have multiple record in the table as per users leave and then later sum up the days monthly or year wise.

Comment: We're not here to *give you some solution asap* - ***YOU*** have to provide what you've tried, show us what you have, explain where you're facing which problem, and **THEN** we'll be glad to help. This is **NOT** a solution-providing service here!

Comment: Dear marc_s, if this is not solution providing platform, then why below every question, there are solution1, solution2, 3, 4, 5 ..... You dont want to ans, then dont comment like this. thanks

Comment: @user3274461: May I know what's the problem you are facing?

Comment: Yup, i dont know how to do this, how to assign date to leaves every time an employee gets some leaves in sql server.

Comment: I think you need one more table with 1:M relation ,Second table may have leave_id(PK),emp_id(FK),rom_date, to_date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your database structure like this

```
Table Leave
emp_id,
leave_id,
leave_Type,
days_applied,
from_date,
to_date,
date_applied


Table Leave Type
leave_Type_id,
leave_Type
```

Note: Above tables are just for e.g. to solve your problem you can change it.

With above structure you can easily calculate leaves taken by employee and also filter by leave type.

Comment: Thank you so so much Mr. Sandip Patil

Comment: Welcome, mark as answer if you feel it solves your problem.

Comment: what is leave_id, please tell me,

Comment: i am not understanding leave_Type_id, can you explain??

Comment: leave_id is a unique primary key to identify each leave individually, leave_type_id is also unique primary key to identify leave type like, sick, vacation and admin. You can skip Leave Type table and instead use 1,2 and 3 values to identify leave type.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you insert individual leave record for each leave against employee_id and leave_type_id wise. Later you can get all records by employee_id.

Comment: Thanks bro, can you please explain a bit more.

Comment: You can create a table like this:
(http://i1152.photobucket.com/albums/p487/subha4study/Capture_zpsff485b51.png)

here empid is foreign_key from employee table and Leave_type_id is foreign_key from LeaveTypeMaster table.